# Swift 4 Set Navigation Attributes for only one View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to make only one view controller's navigation bar translucent and change some of the other attributes.

After the user leaves this VC however I'd like it to go back to 'normal' ie what I have in the AppDelegate.

Do I have to reset each line in the viewWillDisappear? If so what would I use for the background image/shadow image as the default nav bar settings?

```
    // Make Nav Bar Translucent and Set title font/color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)]
```

Comment: You'd need to save the current values into instance properties in `viewWillAppear` before making your changes, and restore them in `viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to set the values in ViewWillApear and reset the values in viewWillDisappear function for having clear transparent navigation bar and normal color navigation bar.

You can use extension on UINavigationController which can set/reset values based on some enum value. Create extension on UIImage which can create image from color to apply as a background image on navigation bar and shadow image.

```
enum NavigationBarMode {
    case normal
    case clear
}

extension UINavigationController {

    func themeNavigationBar(mode: NavigationBarMode) {
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        switch mode {
        case .normal:
            let image = UIImage.fromColor(.white)
            navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
            navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage.fromColor(.lightGray)
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)]
        case .clear:
            let image = UIImage()
            navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
            navigationBar.shadowImage = image
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)]
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    static func fromColor(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }
}
```

now you can call `themeNavigationBar(mode: .transparent)` in `viewWillApear` and call `themeNavigationBar(mode: .normal)` in `viewWillDisappear` to reset. also you can call themeNavigationbar(mode: .normal) if you have common navigationbar settings from you other viewControllers.

There are some Third party cocoapods available which you can use

https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMNavigationBarTransition
https://github.com/DanisFabric/RainbowNavigation

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Wow didn't even think to look for a pod on it.  I'm trying your solution but it's saying there's no type `NavigationBarMode`?

Comment: edited the answer, add NavigationBarMode enum and try